# Parse Double to a specific format

Tags: java, format, number-formatting

I want to parse Double value to a specific format. I don't want it as a string. 
I am trying

```
 DecimalFormat format3DigitsAfterDecimal = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
 double d = 57;
 Double.parseDouble(format3DigitsAfterDecimal.format(d));
```

This returns `57.0`, I want `57.000` returned by format method in double. 
Am I possibly asking wrong question ?

Comment: You can either get a double like `57.0` or you can format it as a String like `57.000`. In the end there is no difference, but the String representation allows you format your double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double doesn't have a specific format.

Getting a Double value as 57.0 or 57.000 is the same for the computer but not for the user.
As a human, you don't read Double, but String representation of Double.

If you want a Double to be displayed with 3 decimal, you have to turn it to String using `DecimalFormat`

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = 57.0;
NumberFormat numFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
numFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
numFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
System.out.println(numFormat.format(d));
```

You can't change the value of a decimal, but you can use NumberFormat to display it with three decimal places by setting minimum and maximum fraction digits like in the example above.